# Where is Netbeans getting the Repository Location from? (SVN)

Tags: svn, netbeans, repository

I created a new project, then I clicked on "Import to Subversion repository" but I had problems with the initial set up so I decided to start again.

For that, I browsed my local repository with SVN, deleted the repository that was created with the command above (from Netbeans) and now that repository is totally gone.

Well, I then deleted my project in Netbeans and created a new one with the same folders name/structure. I was expecting to have that "Import to Subversion repository" option enabled (as this was a new fresh project) but somehow Netbeans remembers things from the 1st attempt and doesn't have that option enabled, it displays all the options, as in the repository existed in SVN.

If I right click and choose Diff or Show Changes, then I can see the Netbeans displays the original folders in the "Repository Location" section, but where is that information coming from (as I deleted that folder from the SVN repository with Tortoise)?

And how can I delete all the information Netbeans has and start again? I was looking for a .svn folder in my project but there's nothing! As said, I deleted the whole project and started again but Netbeans still remembers things, that are not correct!

Many thanks for any tip...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that the NetBeans metadata for the project is still hanging around after you deleted the project initially. When you created the first project did you select to store the metadata in another location or in the project directory? I've had similar problems where I stored it in another location (e.g. ~/Documents/Programming/NetBeansProjects/) and it did not get deleted when I deleted the project to start over. I'd check where your project metadata is being stored and make sure it is getting deleted when you delete the project itself. Also make sure that when you delete the project files you delete the .SVN folder as well (if you are not deleting the root folder, and just its contents). Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Craine, I reviewed all the files again and it turned out that some .svn folders were buried in the folders structure from the project. They were not getting deleted after removing the project, metadata and the root .svn as well as deleting the project folder straight with Tortoise.

Deleting those .svn folders and now Netbeans recognize again that it's a new project.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Great tip, thanks Craine! The metadata can be found by entering `%localappdata%` into the explorer bar (Windows 10) and hitting enter. There should be a `netbeans` folder, and deleting the `svncache` folder did the trick for me.